# Pass command line arguments to Livy - Interactive session

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, livy, hdp

I tried deploying a pyspark application from Jenkins, through livy interactive session.

```
livy_submit --livy-url <edge node> -s sample.py
```

I have a scenario where we would need to pass external parameters, something similar to **"--args"** that is used in livy batch mode. Using --args with livy interactive, throws unknown parameter error.

Is there a way/workaround to do this?

**livy-submit => pip install livy-submit

Answer (score 0):

Achieved it by passing arguments as key-value pair to "--exe-env" parameter.